# TeeChat multiple bar graph Delphi

Tags: delphi, graph, teechart

I am trying to generate a graph where the "y" are quantity and the "x" can only be 5 items, each one has what they have to do and what they have done.

Each item is taken from different queries so I manually load the graph, then I have two problems in the x to put the titles that are different and also I assign the colors of the bars, so for example, put yellow the bars that indicate what it has what to do and blue what he has done.

In graph in the "X" the 0 for example should say house, the 1 car, 2 window, I add the data with Series1.Add (prg_caminata, ''); and Series2.Add (walk_type, ''); where the first tells me what it should have and the second what it has done.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1):

Seems traditional usage of `AddBar` makes what you want:

```
Series3.AddBar(13, 'Car', clBlue);
Series4.AddBar(11, 'Fuel', clRed);
Series3.AddBar(8, 'Dog', clMaroon);
Series4.AddBar(12, 'Food', clGray);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I could not find the instruction

Comment: If problem is solved, you can mark answer as solution (green mark)